# Interact with editor widgets' data in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qtableview, qtgui

I'm using an editable QTableView + QStandardItemModel.

While editing a cell in a table view, I'd like to do something **according to the new input data** in this specific cell when committing the new data into the table view.

To do this, I need the new input data and the current model index (or column & row number).
I tried some slots such as

> virtual void closeEditor (QWidget * editor,
>   QAbstractItemDelegate::EndEditHint hint)

and

> virtual void commitData ( QWidget * editor ).

commitData seems to be what I need, however, the parameter is only the editor and I cannot figure out how to obtain the text in this editor widget.
I looked QTextEdit  but it's not a inherited class of QWidget.

I wonder if there's any way to obtain the data (text) and axis (column, row) of an editor widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to implement your own item delegate, inheriting `QStandardItemDelegate` (or `QAbstractItemDelegate`). There you can override

```
void setModelData ( QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index ) const
```

Simply do you your custom processing and then call `QStandardItemDelegate::setModelData(...)` to make sure that your model is updated with the newly edited data.

Comment: Thanks!
I'll try to write a inherited class like that. :)
It seems there's no easier way to do it.

By the way, I'm not familiar with editor widget, when I call the setModelData , how can I obtain the current activated editor as a paremeter? Or should I write a customized editor too?

The editor widget always confuses me and I cannot find much helpful document about it online. 

(For example, once I can communicate with the editor in commitData, the function I required should be very simple, but I just don't know how to do it.)

Comment: You don't have to call `setModelData()`; it should be called by the view when the editor commits an edit operation.

Answer (score 1):

The [`itemChanged(QStandardItem*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged) signal is emitted by a `QStandardItemModel` whenever an item's data changes.

From the given `QStandardItem`, you can retrieve the row and column directly. To get the displayed text, pass `Qt::DisplayRole` to the item's `data()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much :)


I've tried some signal related to data change, this kind of signal is helpful in most case. However, I still need to do the check even the data is not changed, in case that the editing mode is triggered with default but invalid value (user input is required, no valid default value), and commit before modified.